# Converting the classes with multiple dimension to Bridge design pattern

Tags: design, design-patterns, c++

Bridge design pattern is something which is very confusing and GOF does not do justice with beginners in the definition.

I was asked in my current organisation to add one more dimension to our class and use Bridge pattern for it, knowing nothing about it I went through some blogs and have implemented the same for our code. OFC I cannot paste the code base here so providing some minimal similar example as that in my code base.

Say there is a video class containing 2 dimension: `VideoType` and `VideoProcessor`. These 2 dimensions are independent of each other. And without using the bridge design pattern, this is what the code would have looked like.

```
#include <iostream>

class Video
{
    protected:
    std::string filename;
    public:
    Video(const std::string &filename)
    {
        this->filename = filename;
    }
    virtual void ProcessVideo() = 0;
    virtual void Play() = 0;
};

class NetflixVideoHD : public Video
{
    public:
    NetflixVideoHD(const std::string &filename) : Video(filename) {    }

    void Play()
    {
        std::cout<<"Playing HD Netflix video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }

    void ProcessVideo()
    {
        std::cout<<"Processing HD Netflix video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }
};

class NetflixVideo4KHD : public Video
{
    public:
    NetflixVideo4KHD(const std::string &filename) : Video(filename) {    }

    void Play()
    {
        std::cout<<"Playing 4KHD Netflix video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }

    void ProcessVideo()
    {
        std::cout<<"Processing 4KHD Netflix video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }
};

class YouTubeHD : public Video
{
    public:
    YouTubeHD(const std::string &filename) : Video(filename) {    }

    void Play()
    {
        std::cout<<"Playing HD YouTube video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }

    void ProcessVideo()
    {
        std::cout<<"Processing HD YouTube video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }
};

class YouTube4K : public Video
{
    public:
    YouTube4K(const std::string &filename) : Video(filename) {    }

    void Play()
    {
        std::cout<<"Playing 4K YouTube video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }

    void ProcessVideo()
    {
        std::cout<<"Processing 4K YouTube video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Video *nethd = new NetflixVideoHD("Video.mp4");
    Video *net4khd = new NetflixVideo4KHD("Video.mp4");
    Video *ythd = new YouTubeHD("Video.mp4");
    Video *yt4Khd = new YouTube4K("Video.mp4");

    nethd->ProcessVideo();
    nethd->Play();

    net4khd->ProcessVideo();
    net4khd->Play();

    ythd->ProcessVideo();
    ythd->Play();

    yt4Khd->ProcessVideo();
    yt4Khd->Play();

    delete nethd;
    delete net4khd;
    delete ythd;
    delete yt4Khd;
}
```

Now after converting the same to bridge design pattern by converting one base class to abstract and other to interface, this is how the new code looks like.

```
#include <iostream>

/* One dimension converted to Interface */
class VideoProcessorInterface
{
    public:
    virtual void ProcessVideo(const std::string &filename) = 0;
};

class VideoProcessorHD : public VideoProcessorInterface
{
    public: 
    void ProcessVideo(const std::string &filename)
    {
        std::cout<<"Processing HD video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }
};

class VideoProcessor4KHD : public VideoProcessorInterface
{
    public:
    void ProcessVideo(const std::string &filename)
    {
        std::cout<<"Processing 4K video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }
};

/* Other dimesnion used as abstract class */
class Video
{
    protected:
    std::string filename;
    VideoProcessorInterface *videoProcessor;
 
    public:
    Video(const std::string &filename, VideoProcessorInterface *videoProcessor)
    {
        this->filename = filename;
        this->videoProcessor = videoProcessor;
    }

    virtual void ProcessVideo() = 0;
    virtual void Play() = 0;
};

class NetflixVideo : public Video
{
    public:
    NetflixVideo(const std::string &filename, VideoProcessorInterface *videoProcessor) : Video(filename, videoProcessor) {    }

    void Play()
    {
        std::cout<<"Playing Netflix video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }

    void ProcessVideo()
    {
        std::cout<<"Processing Netflix video in below quality " << filename << std::endl;
        videoProcessor->ProcessVideo(filename);
    }
};

class YouTube : public Video
{
    public:
    YouTube(const std::string &filename, VideoProcessorInterface *videoProcessor) : Video(filename, videoProcessor) {    }

    void Play()
    {
        std::cout<<"Playing YouTube video : " << filename << std::endl;
    }

    void ProcessVideo()
    {
        std::cout<<"Processing YouTube video in below quality " << filename << std::endl;
        videoProcessor->ProcessVideo(filename);
    }
};



int main()
{
    VideoProcessorHD hdVideoProcessor;
    VideoProcessor4KHD f4KVideoProcessor;

    Video *nethd = new NetflixVideo("Video.mp4", &hdVideoProcessor);
    Video *net4khd = new NetflixVideo("Video.mp4", &f4KVideoProcessor);
    Video *ythd = new YouTube("Video.mp4", &hdVideoProcessor);
    Video *yt4Khd = new YouTube("Video.mp4", &f4KVideoProcessor);

    nethd->ProcessVideo();
    nethd->Play();

    net4khd->ProcessVideo();
    net4khd->Play();

    ythd->ProcessVideo();
    ythd->Play();

    yt4Khd->ProcessVideo();
    yt4Khd->Play();

    delete nethd;
    delete net4khd;
    delete ythd;
    delete yt4Khd;
}
```

I just wanted to know whether the above conversion strategy follows bridge design pattern. And what are the issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to know whether the above conversion strategy follows bridge design pattern

Structurally, it is equal to the Bridge pattern, but semantically, I would classify this more as Strategy pattern, which is [structurally the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464524/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bridge-pattern-and-the-strategy-pattern). We talk of a Strategy when a behavioural abstraction gets its own interface and can be switched at runtime - and video processing looks very much like a behaviour for me. But don't mind, I would not be astonished if that is what the one who asked you to introduce the Bridge pattern had in mind.

> what are the issues with it

The first thing I would always ask when introducing any kind of pattern is:

- **Is this really necessary or does it overcomplicates things**?

In case of a video processor, I can imagine of implementations for HD and 4KHD processing which are sufficiently different to justify different classes for them. Still, if we assume for a moment that both implementations are identical, and both classes only differ by some default resolutions, you may consider not to create a class hierarchy and use just a `VideoProcessor` object with the required resolution as a constructor parameter.

Still, you will have to look at the real case, not at some contrived example to make a sensible decision.